# Datepicker not showing up on Custom Post Type page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I'm new to Wordpress/PHP development, and am running into a couple issues while trying to create a datepicker field for a custom post type. I followed a tutorial to add a jquery UI datepicker when someone tries to publish a new post, but the datepicker doesn't show up on that page. When I hit "publish" I get taken to a page where I can input a date manually, but no datepicker metabox shows up. Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here's my custom post type code (apologies for the length!):

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: rundown
* Plugin URI: #
* Version: 1.0
* Author: bjorkland
* Author URI: http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/plugins.php?  plugin_status=all&paged=1&s
* Description: A custom post type
* License: GPL2
*/

class Rundown{

function __construct() {
  add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_custom_post_type' ) );
}
function register_custom_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'rundown', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Rundowns', 'post type general name', 'rundown' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Rundown', 'post type singular name', 'rundown' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Rundown', 'admin menu', 'rundown' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Rundown', 'add new on admin bar', 'rundown' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Rundown', 'rundown' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Rundown', 'rundown' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Rundown', 'rundown' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Rundown', 'rundown' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Rundown', 'rundown' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Rundowns', 'rundown' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Rundowns', 'rundown' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Rundown:', 'rundown' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Rundown found.', 'rundown' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Rundown found in Trash.', 'rundown' ),
    ),

    // Frontend
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'public'             => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,

    // Admin
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-businessman',
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'query_var'     => true,
    'show_in_menu'  => true,
    'show_ui'       => true,
    'supports'      => array(
        'title',
        'author',
        'comments',
    ),
) );

}
}

$Rundown = new Rundown;

function rundown_add_info_meta_box() {
add_meta_box( 'rundown_meta_box',
      __( 'Event Info', 'rundown' ),
    'rundown_render_event_info_metabox',
    'event',
    'side',
    'core'
);
}
   add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rundown_add_info_metabox' );

function rundown_render_event_info_metabox( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'rundown-event-info-nonce' );

$event_start_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event-start-date', true );
$event_end_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event-end-date', true );

$event_start_date = ! empty( $event_start_date ) ? $event_start_date : time();

$event_end_date = ! empty( $event_end_date ) ? $event_end_date : $event_start_date;



}
function rundown_admin_script_style( $hook ) {
    global $post_type;

if ( 'post.php' == $hook || 'post-new.php' == $hook ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'upcoming-events',
        SCRIPTS . 'script.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ),
        '1.0',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'jquery-ui-calendar',
        STYLES . 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css',
        false,
        '1.10.4',
        'all'
    );
}
}
  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rundown_admin_script_style' );

?>

   <label for="rundown-event-start-date"><?php _e( 'Event Start Date:', 'rundown' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat rundown-event-date-input" id="rundown-event-start-date" type="text" name="rundown-event-start-date" placeholder="Format: February 18, 2014" value="<?php echo date( 'F d, Y', $event_start_date ); ?> " />

    <label for="rundown-event-end-date"><?php _e( 'Event End Date:', 'rundown' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat rundown-event-date-input" id="rundown-event-end-date" type="text" name="rundown-event-end-date" placeholder="Format: February 18, 2014" value="<?php echo date( 'F d, Y', $event_end_date ); ?>" />
```

And here is my jQuery code, in a script.js file in my wp-includes/js folder:

```
(function( $ ) {

$( '#rundown-event-start-date' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#rundown-event-end-date' ).datepicker( 'option', 'minDate', selectedDate );
    }
});
$( '#rundown-event-end-date' ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ){
        $( '#rundown-event-start-date' ).datepicker( 'option', 'maxDate', selectedDate );
    }
});

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: I thought the problem might have had to do with where my "label for's" are placed, but when placed inside the <? ?> tags I was getting an unexpected end syntax error....